# Caching JavaScript Library for whole domain

Tags: javascript, html, caching, browser

I have URL re-writing enabled, and I have lots of unique URL's like below, a bit like YouTube:

```
https://example.com/f/HyhsuLk/ksi
```

The page that loads uses a rather large JavaScript library, and the first time you hit the page above, it takes a couple of seconds to show the page. All subsequent visits to the same page are very quick (I am assuming because all the assets including the large JavaScript library have been cached)

If the I then go to a new URL, for example:

```
https://example.com/f/HyhsIueh/poi
```

Which loads basically the exact same page, same large JavaScript asset etc.. It takes a few seconds to load again, like it is re-downloading the JavaScript file, but then all subsequent visit to that page are quick.

So I have two questions:

1. Why is it re-downloading the same assets when the URL changes (if that's what's happening)
2. How do I cache the JavaScript library so it is used on all pages and not re-downloaded for new URL's.

The JavaScript file is included via a relative path to the file on my website.

It resolves the exact same path on both pages, in fact all pages as it is using the same header template file.

I am sending the expires date as 1 year in the future and a max-age of 360.

Comment: You can add a header when delivering your files through Apache to let the browser know, when to cache or to reload

Comment: Thanks the reply @JnnMgdls although I think you have misunderstood my question. I understand how caching works via headers etc, my question is about caching with different URL's that load the same page.

Comment: How is the js library included? What paths does it resolve to on the two pages? What cache headers are sent for it?

Comment: Hmm… "*It takes a few seconds to load again, like it is re-downloading the JavaScript file*" - that can't be a single js file. What about the other resources on the two pages?

Comment: Why can't it be a single JS file? Either way, the page takes a long time to load like it the first time it has ever seen the page. Which I guess it is based on the URL, but the actual page and all the assets have already been downloaded.